# jQuery conflict

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run the following jQuery to change the text of my username and password boxes so that they do not need a label (inside `<script>` tags):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#user_login1').val('Username');
    $('#user_pass1').val('Password');
    $('#user_login1').focus(function(){
        $('#user_login1').val('');
    });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    $('#user_pass1').focus(function(){
        $('#user_pass1').val('');
    });​
});​
```

The code works on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6UpH/2/) **[updated]** (proving it's a WP issue not a jQuery issue).

I have tried without the `function($)` modifier and replacing the `$` with `jQuery` but to no avail.

<del>I am "trusting" the folks that code [Use Google Libraries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/) to sort the jQuery out on my site meaning my jQuery include looks like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`</del>

**EDIT 1**

Now not calling it at all, as when I add `wp_enque_script('jquery');` it breaks the admin pages showing nothing but a blank white page. Never the less jQuery gets called like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1"></script>
```

**END EDIT 1**

**EDIT 2**

- Changed spelling to `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`
- Changed `$` in jQuery to `jQuery`
- It has become apparent that jQuery is broken site wide, save wp-admin

Still not working.

The above location (edit 1) that the jQuery is called from does exist.

I noticed that it calls `jQuery.noConflict()`  twice. Once in the output of the page, and once at the bottom of the jQuery file.

**END EDIT 2**

**EDIT 3**

In response to Chip Bennett here is the call found in `functions.php` of my theme.

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

It also occured to me I had not posted up my website for testing, outside of the jsfiddle code. The form I am trying to get working is on the top right of this page:

http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/

**END EDIT 3**

**EDIT 4**

Replaced the jQuery in edit 3 with the following based off of chip bennett's answer

```
function wpse45377_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse45377_enqueue_scripts' );
```

I also thought to look at the console output in Chrome's dev tools and got this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined   Line:25
    (anonymous function)
```

The code it is referencing is this

```
25: <script type='text/javascript'>jQuery.noConflict();
26: /* <![CDATA[ */
27: var tb_pathToImage='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/thickbox/loadingAnimation.gif';
28: var tb_closeImage='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/thickbox/tb-close.png';
29: /* ]]> */
30: </script>
```

**END EDIT 4**

Which is the same version of jQuery that jsFiddle uses so I can't understand why this isn't working. A little help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try `wp_enqueue_script` to enqueue jQuery, which is in the `/includes` folder of WordPress installation?

Comment: I have previously tried that. My installation was loading it by default until I installed the plugin in an attempt to circumvent my problem. I have no real qualms reverting though

Comment: Have edited post to display additional findings

Comment: You misspelled `enqueue`, it should be `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`. And you should probably check if the jQuery gets loaded on the appropriate page, which is the login page.

Comment: Also try replacing  `$` with  `jQuery`

Comment: have added `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` to `functions.php` and replaced `$` with `jQuery` but to no avail. It seems jQuery site wide is now gone.

Comment: Can we see your entire callback and hook that you use to enqueue jQuery? Also: are you trying to enqueue jQuery on the front end, or in the admin?

Comment: See edited post

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This is what I had to do to get it to work

Add the following right after `<head>` in `header.php`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Rem out any reference to `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`

Add this script just before the ''

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#user_login1').val('Username');
            $('#user_pass1').val('Password');
            $('#user_login1').focus(function(){
                var un = $('#user_login1').val();
                if(un == 'Username'){
                    $('#user_login1').val('');
                }
            });
            $('#user_pass1').focus(function(){
                var pwd = $('#user_pass1').val();
                if(pwd == 'Password'){
                    $('#user_pass1').val('');
                }
            });
            $('#user_login1').focusout(function(){
                if($('#user_login1').val().length < 1){
                    $('#user_login1').val('Username');
                }
            });
            $('#user_pass1').focusout(function(){
                if($('#user_pass1').val().length < 1){
                    $('#user_pass1').val('Password');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I may have gone a a *little* crazy on the remming, but I needed it to work and now it does.

Comment: This method may have worked for you, but this **will break** other Plugins, as you 1) are using a non-core-bundled version of jQuery, and 2) may end up with jQuery being enqueued twice, since you're hard-coding the script link, rather than enqueueing.

Comment: the jquery breaks whenever I use the wp_enqueue_script tag. I **know** this is not best practice, but it works as opposed to what should work. For some reason wp_enqueue_script get's called too far down even when I set priority 1 so it breaks the js on my site.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Edit 3:

> In response to Chip Bennett here is the call found in functions.php of my theme.
>
> ```
> wp_deregister_script('jquery');
> wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
> ```

I see two issues:

1. You need to put your enqueue inside a **callback**, hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts` (for the frontend) or `admin_enqueue_scripts` (for the admin back-end), like so:

   ```
   <?php
   function wpse45377_enqueue_scripts() {
       wp_deregister_script('jquery');
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse45377_enqueue_scripts' );
   ?>
   ```
2. You're *deregistering* jQuery, without *re-registering* it. I would recommend **not de-registering** jQuery; but if you **must** (and only if you **absolutely** must), you have to **register it again** before you can use it. I would recommend simply removing the `deregister_script()` call entirely:

   ```
   <?php
   function wpse45377_enqueue_scripts() {
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse45377_enqueue_scripts' );
   ?>
   ```

That should fix your problem, and would explain why jQuery seems to have just "disappeared": **you made it disappear, by de-registering it**. :)

#### Edit

Looking at your source, you've got jQuery scripts outputting in your document head **before your jQuery is being linked**:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>jQuery.noConflict();
/* <![CDATA[ */
var tb_pathToImage='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/thickbox/loadingAnimation.gif';
var tb_closeImage='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/thickbox/tb-close.png';
/* ]]> */
</script>

<!-- iMember360 -->
<meta name='generator'   content='iMember360 (v3.3.012) for WordPress 3.3.1' />
<link title='Membership site system for WordPress and Infusionsoft' type='text/html' rel='help' hreflang='en' href='http://www.iMember360.com' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
var tb_pathToImage='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/thickbox/loadingAnimation.gif';
var tb_closeImage='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/thickbox/tb-close.png';
function payf_popup() {
  tb_show('Notice:','#TB_inline?height=300&amp;width=400&amp;inlineId=PayfInfoDiv');
}
</script>
<!-- /iMember360 -->

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Elite Traders Group &raquo; Feed" href="http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Elite Traders Group &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/comments/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Elite Traders Group &raquo; Home Comments Feed" href="http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/home/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='thickbox-css'  href='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=20111117' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-my-login-css'  href='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login/theme-my-login.css?ver=6.1.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
```

Notice that you have scripts outputting before the last line of the above code, which is:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
```

Where/how are you adding the jQuery scripts to your document head? If they are hard-coded in your document head, that's your problem. You need to enqueue them, and make jQuery a dependency.

Comment: copied and pasted both. the top one 500 error'd me and the bottom didn't fix. Added some additional info to OP.

Comment: Yeah, there was a typo. I had put `deregister_script()` instead of `wp_deregister_script()`. (Note: always check code snippets; don't blindly copy-pasta.) Also: if the second one didn't work: are you trying to enqueue on the **front end** or in the **admin**?

Comment: Also, saying "*didn't fix...*" isn't nearly descriptive enough. Did the script get enqueued (you can tell by viewing source)?

Comment: trying to get it for the front end. also, op is now sorted. Commented then edited.

Comment: still no luck with the deregister script. it is calling the script here: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://elitetradersgroup.com.au/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1"></script>` it seems it's called after the `jQuery.noConflict()` though..

Comment: See updated answer. Your jQuery **is being enqueued properly**. It appears, though, that you've got jQuery scripts outputting *before* jQuery in the document head.

Comment: **Why are you still trying to de-register jQuery?**

Comment: I am not trying, to de register was just seeing if it would work. Did a search all for `jQuery.noConflict()` and I can't locate where it is in my theme. Must be being called as part of WP. Is there a way to call the enqueue with a higher priority?

Comment: "*Is there a way to call the enqueue with a higher priority?*" - that depends. How are you outputting the jQuery scripts in the document head? Are they hard-coded in `header.php`, or are they enqueued/hooked?

Comment: as I said, I couldn't find the `noConflict` in a search all on my theme. there is no call for `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` outside the one in the op. here is a link to my `header.php` file http://pastebin.com/AX0EM0tz